# How do I pass dropdown value from ShieldUI dropdown to contoller?

Tags: shieldui

I am trying to understand how to submit a drop-down selected value back to the MVC controller.  I have a ShielUI DIV below followed by original MVC Using statement.   How do I change the submit statment to something like $("#mainForm").submit()); or any other approach?

thank you for your help.

```
    <div>
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                <label for="comboBoxTech">Select from list</label>
                <br />
                @(Html.ShieldComboBox()
                    .Width(200)
                    .Name("comboBoxTech")
                    .AutoComplete(ab => ab.Enabled(true))
                    .DataSource(dsb => dsb.Data(dropdown.ToArray())))
                <br />
                <br />
                @(Html.ShieldButton()
                    .Name("submit")
                    .Html("Submit")
                    .Events(e => e.Click(@<text>
                        function() {
                        $("#mainForm").submit());
                        }
                    </text>)))
            </div>
            <div class="imageDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateJN", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.DropDownList("JobsList", string.Empty) and <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

got it figured out using a $.post (which is same as $.Ajax.  worked good.

```
    <div>
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                <label for="comboBoxTech">Select from list</label>
                <br />
                @(Html.ShieldComboBox()
                    .Width(200)
                    .Name("comboBoxTech")
                    .AutoComplete(ab => ab.Enabled(true))
                    .DataSource(dsb => dsb.Data(dropdown.ToArray())))
                <br />
                <br />
                @(Html.ShieldButton()
                    .Name("submit")
                    .Html("Submit")
                    .Events(e => e.Click(@<text>
                        function(e) {
                            $.post("Home/ValidateJN", { comboBoxTech : $("#comboBoxTech").val()});
                        }
                    </text>)))
            </div>
            <div class="imageDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```